# Why is my anchor tags not working properly?

Tags: php, html, anchor, tableofcontents

So I went ahead an answered my own question and created a TOC, which works, it spits out everything I wanted, accept the anchor tags don't work. it will not jump down the page to where the appropriate h1-6 tags are.

I have the following php:

```
public function table_of_contents(&$content, $HeaderParameter){
    //Creat Empty variables
    $HeaderNums = "";
    $ContentLink = "";
    $IndentLast = 1;
    //Creates a single string of header identifier. eg: "1234"
    foreach($HeaderParameter as $Num){
        $HeaderNums.= $Num;
    }
    //Setup header to search for our headers specified by user
    if (preg_match_all('/<h(['.$HeaderNums.'])(.*?)>(.*?)(<\/h['.$HeaderNums.']>)/', $content, $Result)){
        // Start Table
        $ContentLink.="<ul id='TB_UL'>";
        // Go through each result and add to our list
        foreach ($Result[0] as $key => $title){
            //Get header text
            $HeaderText = strip_tags($Result[0][$key]);
            // If user assign an ID then get it so that we can add our on
            $TagIdRegexOutput = split('"',$Result[2][$key]);
            // Check if user has already set an id, if so use theres
            if($TagIdRegexOutput[0]){
                $TagRef = $TagIdRegexOutput[1];
            }
            else{
                $TagRef = $HeaderText;
            }
            //Set a level.
            $IndentPosCurrent = $Result[1][$key];
            //Create link to header
            $ContentLink.='<li class="TB_Level' . $Result[1][$key] .'"><a class="TB_Link" href="#'.$TagRef.'">'.$HeaderText.'</a>'.'</li>';
            // Create header tag
            $HeaderTag = "h".$Result[1][$key];
            // Replace header in content with our assign id
            $content = str_replace($Result[0][$key], "<$HeaderTag"." id='$TagRef' ".">$HeaderText</$HeaderTag>", $content);
        }
        // End List
        $ContentLink.="</ul> <!-- TB_Main-->";
    }
    echo $ContentLink;      
}
```

Which spits out html like such:

```
<ul id="TB_UL">
    <li class="TB_Level1"><a class="TB_Link" href="#Test">Test</a></li>
    <li class="TB_Level2"><a class="TB_Link" href="#More Test">More Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

The #Test and #More Test are: `<h1>Test</h1>` and `<h2>More Test</h2>`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Either add an anchor tag to the correct position in the HTML or use `id`s:

Anchor:

```
<h1><a name="Test">Test</a></h1>
```

ID:

```
<h1 id="Test">Test</h1>
```

EDIT: I would suggest the second approach, as I believe the `name` attribute is no longer valid for anchor tags in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features  (thanks to @Alohci for providing the link below).  On the other hand, if you have to support a lot of users on REALLY old browsers, the first one is preferable.

Comment: Actually, the name attribute on `<a>` elements is [obsolete but conforming](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) (i.e. it is valid, but should not be used.)

Comment: well, then you have the luxury of choosing between both solutions I offered above. :)

Answer (score -1):

`#`-links go to an anchor tag:

```
<a name="Test">Anchor</a>
<a href="#Test">Go to Anchor</a>
```

You don't have any in that output.